# How to keep dropdown open on mouse over using webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.className("status"));
WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.id("7oSL5I7egLSgqmGVYpF_lG6VyY3ZR7SArK6pYZVU3g"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(we1).build().perform();
we1.click();
```

Here I am performing a mousehover on the `we` element which is performing fine but I can't keep the dropdown `we` open for further selection of `we1` (a checkbox)

Comment: I assume you're talking about the Selenium 2.0 WebDriver API. If you aren't, please clarify and fix the tags.

Comment: Yes I am talking about Selenium 2.0 Webdriver API.

Comment: Do you really need to actually keep it open to select the dropdown element? Can you not just do `we1.Click();`?

Comment: Its actually a dropdown having checkbox selections and I want the last checkbox to be selected, for that I want the dropdown to be open till few seconds in order to do perform the check box selection.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would expect an actions chain to be joined together like this:

```
builder.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(we1).click().perform();
```

This should then perform all required actions in the chain without pause and without losing hover focus.  The other option of course is to break this into two distinct actions like so:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);

builder.moveToElement(we).perform();
waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.visibiltiyOf(we1));
builder.moveToElement(we1).click().perform();
```

The explicit wait is used to ensure that the element "we1" is visible before trying to hover over and click on it.